# Remove quotation marks from values in JavaScript Array Object

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to get my JSON encoded array formatted properly.  Here is my PHP MySQL Query:

```
$query = "SELECT date, value1, value2
            FROM testdata
            ORDER BY date ASC";  


         $result = mysql_query($query);
         $myChartData = array();
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $myChartData[] = $row;
                        }

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData = <?php echo json_encode($myChartData); ?>;
```

From the console, the object looks like this:

```
[Object { date="2011-02-23", value1="133034", value2="12105.78"},
 Object { date="2011-02-24", value1="122290", value2="12068.50"},
 Object { date="2011-03-08", value1="453142", value2="12214.38"}]
```

The quotation marks around the date stays, but the ones on value1 and value2 need to be stripped out.

Self-teaching noob at all of this...Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should convert those strings `value1` and `value2` to numbers  before you JSON encode.

Comment: You should consider JSON as a data format. It's a native JavaScript object so it's fast and you don't need the same amount of parsing to get to your data. http://www.secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

Comment: @ControlAltDel not true. "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array" http://json.org

Comment: @Diodeus: That's what he is doing. `json_encode($myChartData)` creates JSON. And JSON is not JavaScript. It is format that was *inspired* by JavaScript's object literal syntax. That's all.

Comment: Did you actually attempt to access those values?  `console.log(yourArray[0].value1);`

Comment: Felix: I was looking at it from a client perspective. I don't do much PHP. :)

Comment: @ D3mon-1stVFW:  So far I've tried  JSON.stringify(chartData); and then have tried to manipulate the data from there, but the examples I've seen are geared toward changing column names, not the actual data.

Comment: @ Michael - I ran console.log(chartData), and that's what gave me the output I listed in the second code box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple javascript solution:

```
function formatChartData(data) {
    for(var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
        data[i].value1 = parseInt(data[i].value1, 10);
        data[i].value2 = parseFloat(data[i].value2);
    }
    return data;
}

var chartData = formatChartData(<?php echo json_encode($myChartData); ?>);
```

Comment: Joe, so far this did what I asked to do!  I have to plug it in to the whole script to see if it produces the charts, but the output looks like this:

[Object { date="2011-02-23", value1=133034, value2=12105.78},
 Object { date="2011-02-24", value1=122290, value2=12068.5},
 Object { date="2011-03-08", value1=453142, value2=12214.38}]

Which leaves me wondering if it's a fix for something I did wrong in the first place, or what...  I'll work on it, thanks!

Comment: Well, it definitely works!  Thanks Joe!  Although, I think it's fixing a mistake I've made in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

> The quotation marks around the date stays, but the ones on value1 and value2 need to be stripped out.

There are no quotation marks! What you see as a visual representation of the data contained in  `chartData`. In this case it is an array with three objects, each having three properties containing **strings**.
What you want is to convert some of these strings into **numbers** (integers, floating point).

---

#### The correct way

It seems you are not storing the data correctly in your DB. If the values were numbers, they would be encoded as such.

The only reasonable solution is to fix it at that end. That means you have to define the data types of your DB fields properly.

---

#### The workaround

If, for some reason, you cannot fix the DB (you should try really hard), you have the possibility to convert the strings to numbers

- in PHP, using [`intval` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and/or [`floatval` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)
- or in JavaScript with the [unary plus operator *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29):

  ```
  var number = +string;
  ```

If you are new to JavaScript, you might want to read [*Working with Objects*  <sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Felix.  I'm much better with RDB than I am javascript, and I even went back and double-checked to make sure I didn't do anything stoopid when I created the DB.

In the MySQL DB, date is stored as a 'date", value1 is stored as int(11) and value2 is stored as decimal (8,2).

Which brings up one of the puzzles I've found in researching my problem.  The dataset is being sent to Amcharts, and the other guys had problems with the column names in quotes.  I was a bit miffed as to why I had the opposite issue...

Comment: I was wondering if what I was viewing in the console was the actual data being passed to Amcharts.  Still trying to get my head around this...

Comment: Mmmh. That's interesting. Maybe my PHP/DB is a bit rusty, but if the data type in the DB is correct, you should get the correct data type in PHP. What is an example for the output `var_dump($row)` in your loop?

Comment: Rats.  The output looks like:

array(3) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2011-02-23" ["value1"]=> string(6) "133034" ["value2"]=> string(8) "12105.78" } 
array(3) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2011-02-24" ["value1"]=> string(6) "122290" ["value2"]=> string(8) "12068.50" } 
array(3) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2011-03-08" ["value1"]=> string(6) "453142" ["value2"]=> string(8) "12214.38" }

Comment: So it looks like it's getting value1 and value2 as strings (?)

Comment: This is killing me.  I do a sql dump of the table, and everything looks fine.  No quotes around the value1 and value2 data.  How the heck is it getting converted to a string when I bring it in with a PHP query?

Comment: I only found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026853/mysql-bigints-php-and-auto-string-int-casting-flip-flopping Maybe it's like this... maybe you always get strings back, I don't remember anymore, actually... but it seems to be really strange.

Comment: I guess that must be it Felix.  Just to double-check myself, I did the same thing with mysql's own tables (ones I didn't build) and var_dump shows those int's as strings as well.  So in everything else I've built, the numbers work out fine.  But when it's pushed into a javascript object, it has to be cleaned up?

Answer (score 0):

JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK will remove the double quotes from the numeric values in your JSON string.

Example: https://3v4l.org/ip6GN

```
$v = json_decode('[{"id":"1","name":"Jack","username":"Jack1","age":"23"}]');

echo 'Normal:' . \PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($v) . \PHP_EOL . \PHP_EOL;

echo 'Numeric Check:' . \PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($v, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK). \PHP_EOL .
```

Numeric Check:
{"id":1,"name":"Jack","username":"Jack1","age":23}